# resend ajax request changing only one attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to make an ajax request in the success function but i need to pass it a different 'guidlist'.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my.ashx",
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        cmd: 3, //poll database for job status
        guidlist: guidList
                },
    success: function(){
    $.ajax(this);<-all the same except I need to change what i am passing in for guidlist
}
})
```

Comment: You could put all this into a function with your desired parameter

Comment: is something that is returned from `my.ashx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to send the request - then recursively call it from inside your `success` handler.  Be careful though to avoid infinite loops.

```
function sendRequest(param) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "my.ashx",
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            cmd: 3, //poll database for job status
            guidlist: param
                    },
        success: function(){
            if(param == [something])
                sendRequest(newParam);
        }
    });
}

sendRequest(guidList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your script return json that you want to pass to another ajax call. So try this :

```
function myAjaxSend(param) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "my.ashx",
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            cmd: 3, //poll database for job status
            guidlist: param
        },
        success: function(json) {
            // condition to prevent infinit loop
            if(json.otherParam !== undefined) {
                myAjaxSend(json.otherParam);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Two issues: first, you need to have `guidlist: param` inside your `data` element; second, this code will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes thanks, that was for the idea. The condition to prevent infinit loop could be anything that I can't guess, so I didn't wrote anything. Edited though.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to making the second ajax call inside the success function of the first ajax call. Also, the data received from the first ajax call can be referenced in the second ajax call, if desired. See below for an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my.ashx",
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        cmd: 3, //poll database for job status
        guidlist: guidList
    },
    success: function(whatigotback) {
        $.ajax({

            url: "my.ashx",
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                cmd: 3, //poll database for job status
                guidlist: whatigotback
            },
            success: function(newgotback){
                //alert(newgotback);
            } //END 2nd success
        }); //END second AJAX
    } //END 1st success callback
}); //END first AJAX
```

Comment: Pretty ugly... He definitly should go for a recursive call

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the option before sending it again.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my.ashx",
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        cmd: 3, //poll database for job status
        guidlist: guidList
    },
    success: function(){
        this.data.guidlist = anotherguidlist;
        $.ajax(this);
    }
})
```